# Details for Kasina Meditation

Tags: reference-request, meditation-samatha

I've searched through the web and also Wikipedia regarding Kasina meditation and could not find detailed information. Can the meditation object be anything? (Say anything green or blue for those Kasina meditations?)

How does one concentrate on the object? Any thought or mental note (like green green? Earth?) Is the breath watched like in Anapanasati?

Comment: Did you look in the Visuddhimagga?

Comment: Thanks @SankhaKulathantille I did find what I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here in this answer I am going to give some resources I found in the web and not going to copy and past anything here as the process is quite lengthy and detailed. You could learn about Kasina meditation from "[Visuddhimagga (Path of purificaiton)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf)". If your refer page 117 and onwards describe the details about "Earth kasióa". If you need a shorter version please refer [here](http://hudsoncress.net/hudsoncress.org/html/library/buddhism/The%20Pali%20Line/course/files/bit-61_earth_kasina.htm).

Further you could refer [this](http://hudsoncress.net/hudsoncress.org/html/library/buddhism/The%20Pali%20Line/course/files/earth_kasina.htm) page which describe how the create "Earth Kasina"(object) and describe how to do the meditation in details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

There are 10 Kasina meditations. They are categorized due to the object that meditater concentrate in meditation. Meditation method cannot be anything. If you use non-kasina object, it is just loose the time and you will never be able to concentrate. Anapanasathi is not included into Kasina Meditation.

When you select meditation method, it is better to meet a teacher. Best option is Sangha. Those Kasinas are here because of a reason. Meditation is like medicine. Those Kasinas are prescribed due to the characteristic of the student. Those color Kasinas are suitable for people who have angry. Other Kasinas are suitable for anyone.

Basically first you should follow Śīla with at least five percepts for some time(depends on person) before start the meditation.

So Those 10 Kasinas are,

1. Patawi Kasina (Concentrates on Solids)
2. Aapo Kasina (Concentrates on Liquid, best option is water)
3. Thejo Kasina (Concentrates on Heat)
4. Wayo Kasina (Concentrates on Air)
5. Nila Kasina (Concentrates on Blue color)
6. Pitha Kasina (Concentrates on Yellow color)
7. Lohitha Kasina (Concentrates on Red Color)
8. Odhatha Kasina (Concentrates on White Color)
9. Aloka Kasina (Concentrates on Light)
10. Awakasa Kasina (Concentrates on Space)

**1. Patawi Kasina**

That method is the method that has translated as Earth Kasina. But the correct meaning is the solid. During the meditation the meditater use self created Solid object. Usually we use clay(which use to make Bricks).

**2. Aapo Kasina**

Use water as the liquid. normal way of doing the meditation is done with looking at natural lake or tank filled with water.

**3. Thejo Kasina**

Here meditater concentrates on heat. the heat must not be unbearable and very low.

**4.Wayo Kasina**

This concentrates on air. hence air cannot be seen, meditator can use the breeze or waving leaves in a tree.

**5-8 Nila, Pitha, Lohitha and Odhata Kasinas**

Those Kasinas represents Blue, Yellow, Red, White respectively. Here use Wide single colored image as the object.

**9. Aloka Kasina**

This is the light Kasina. use candle light or oil lamp light as the object. Don't use electric bulbs,LEDs  and other powerful light sources. because they will harm to your eye.

**10. Awakasa Kasina**

Here we targets on empty space around us. (The free space in between objects)

It is better to make your object by yourself before meditation when needed. As a example there is no need of make Awakasa Kasina. you have to just find a good place.

these Kasinas are to enter the samadhi. first we look (or feel) at the object with continually concentrate the object in mind. when we do light Kasina, we say(Think) Light, Light, Light, Light............ until we can imagine the object with mind for long time.
then we should meditate with the imagined object.

please make sure that you meditate targeting vipassanā Meditation. vipassanā targets on understanding true nature of ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://home.comcast.net/~turning.point.meditation/kasina/kasina.pdf) goes into detail about how to construct and use a colored-wheel kasina device. I have been using this 'method' for a few weeks now to some good effect...there is something about being able to concentrate on a tangible visual object that makes it easier for a beginner like myself to cultivate and sustain concentration.