# Did the Buddha prescribe other meditations besides breath meditation? (for concentration, jhana)

Tags: meditation-recommendation, jhana

After reading [Ajahn Brahm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XKN6C8), [Leigh Brasington](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017JJOXQ6), and Ayya Khema's books on meditation, I have not been able to reach the jhanas through breath meditation.

If I stay with the breath long enough to reach "access concentration", or at least, if the breath does become fine and imperceptable, I do not experience any bliss or pleasant feelings, and my mind asks, "Now what? Nothing is happening."

Are there stories of the Buddha recommending different styles of meditation (for concentration leading to jhana) depending on the individual disposition of the listener?

I've struggled with aversion and craving not to be. So would the Buddha, for example, prescribe metta meditation here? Please give references. Thank you.

Comment: Did not see the question, sorry. I am looking more for confirmation in the suttas that the Buddha did indeed prescribe different meditation methods (for concentration leading to jhana) to listeners of different dispositions. But seeing [your answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/29832/8619), that may be enough. Thank you.

Comment: Found [this question on kasinas](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/details-for-kasina-meditation) but nothing said on the disposition of the meditator.

Comment: You might want to ask a different question, about "joy" or "*piti*", but there are existing topics about about that too -- [piti](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=piti) and [joy](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=joy).